# seek the lower ancestor in a binary tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I wanna find the lower ancestor in a binary tree, and what i do is first, list the fathers of each node, then compare the list and the last item in common is the lower ancestry.

I have this code:

```
def ancesters(self, node, list= []):
    if self.seekNode(node) != False:
        if node < self.id:
            list.append(self.id)
            return self.left.ancesters(node)
        elif node > self.id:
            list.append(self.id)
            return self.right.ancesters(node)
        elif self.id == node:
            list.append(self.id)
            return list
    else:
        return False
```

the function seekNode works, and this method too, but when i use the method twice, shows the list of ancestor of the last call, example:

i have this tree:

```
               2
               |
                ---
                   5
                  ---
                 3   6
```

and when i call the method ancesters(6), the list will be (2,5,6), and when i call again to search the fathers of 3, shows (2,5,6,2,5,3).

so, when i set the parameter (list=[]) why the list does not initialize and save the list value?.
I call the method with the same object, in this case will be the node (root) of the tree. the nodes are instance of the node (root) of the tree.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Don't use names from standard library (like "list") as variables or parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, do not use mutable object (like list) as a default value.
This is **Anti-Pattern**, because in Python the default value is shared between all function calls. so it must be immutable. popular option is None and condition `if not None: ...`

You can also read [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html)